# Nginx Reverse proxy + SYN Flood

Tags: nginx, iptables

We're running a nginx reverse proxy cluster, forwarding traffic to our main website, this enables us to filter out unwanted traffic/users etc, and send them off else where, now we have a few issues with SYN floods where the requests a second is overflowing the proxy + the main server causing them to become unavailable.

Is there any ip tables magic that can 
A) Rate limit SYN packets / connections to HTTP
B) Block it all together if packets a second is malicious

or any advice how to use limit_rate_zone in nginx, I've googled and tried to apply a few new results and none of them work and the websites are still unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m connlimit --connlimit-above 2 --connlimit-mask 32 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [syn cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_cookies) enabled? Other then that, there's [plenty of places](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-limit-linux-syn-attacks.html) that can give you rules for IPTables to rate limit syn packets.

Comment: Hi, we have SYN Cookies enabled on the reverse proxy and on the main webservers. Those rules are still not helping, the reverse proxies nginx stops responding and displays 503/500 errors, but the main webservers NGINX responds as if there is nothing going on. Could varnish be more useful here?

Comment: Okay, you're confusing things here.  Based on your initial question, I never would have suspected that.  What it sounds like you are seeing is connectivity issues between the proxy and the main server.  If you were seeing syn floods, just your proxy servers would be non-responsive, your real webservers would be working fine (unless you expose them to the internet for some reason).  Can you elaborate a bit more on the issues you are seeing?  I'd suggest editing your question to tell us what symptoms you are seeing, rather then what you think the issue is.